# Why is the accepted answer not pinned to the top?

Tags: bug

We currently have the highest-rated answer pinned to the top and not the accepted one.

With the [meta question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13811/do-we-want-accepted-answers-to-be-pinned-to-the-top) currently at 23 for pinning the accepted answer and 21 for pinning the highest-rated answer, why is the opposite policy currently in effect?

I'm tagging with "bug" because it looks like "unexpected behavior in the system that needs to be fixed".

Comment: [This was not the vote count at the time of implementation](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13811/do-we-want-accepted-answers-to-be-pinned-to-the-top#comment52612_13811) Based on this comment though the decision might now be reversed, although perhaps right now it's too close to call.

Comment: And it's 22-22 now. It indeed looks too close to call.

Comment: Related: *[Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/)*  and *[Do we want accepted answers to be pinned to the top?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13811/)*.