# Are accepted answers generally good answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

This question is different from [Do we want accepted answers to be pinned to the top?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13811/do-we-want-accepted-answers-to-be-pinned-to-the-top). I read the accepted answer to [Why do ice cubes come out easier from top trays?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21942/why-do-ice-cubes-come-out-easier-from-top-trays?rq=1). I understand what it's saying. I think it's a good answer. I actually read it because it was accepted and then found it a good answer and upvoted it.

Comment: so what’s your point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Accepted* and *most upvoted* serve two different functions.

An accepted answer is one the question asker found *personally* more useful and allows them to personally reward a post in addition to any upvote.  The most upvoted answers are, in general and outside the specific needs of the asker, of good quality and the majority of users found them most useful.  Those are two different purposes.

We should not think of them as related operations - they're independent of each other.

Comment: It doesn't quite answer it directly but I can kind of see it. I guess accepted answers solve the problem and I can kind of see that. For example, AsafKaragila's answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1839913/ solved the problem so it got accepted and I can kind of see myself how it does so. Same for the accepted answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75945/w.

Comment: Really, I'm reading between the lines and seeing how the arrow of time would be a natural evolution of the universe and the example of the candle is something like that.